# Is probability meaningful in cases of infinity?

Tags: probability, infinity

Is it meaningful to speak of probability in cases of infinity?

For instance, consider me having an infinite line of balls arranged in the manner: -

Red, Green, Blue, Red, Green, Blue, Red.......

Now, I'm picking a ball randomly from this line. Am I allowed to ask the question, "What is the probability that the ball you picked is Green?" And if an answer exists, what would it be?

My gut feeling is that the probability doesn't change, i.e. it still remains $1/3$ (just as in the case of $3$ balls of different color). But I'm not able to justify this mathematically. It's because I thought that in this case, the number of red, green and blue balls would all be infinitely many, and so the probability computation would essentially involve infinity, making me doubt the question's validity.

I mean, in this case, by definition,

$P$ (picking a green ball) = (No of green balls)/ (Total no of all the balls)
= $∞ / ∞$, which is undefined.

Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: How would you characterize 'picking a ball randomly from this line'?

Comment: @copper.hat: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Well, to some extent, the issue is how to characterize picking something randomly from a countable set. You cannot have a uniform probability in this case. However, in your example, since the pattern repeats, you are really only selecting one number from $1,2,3$, so you can assign a uniform probability here since there are only three outcomes (or at least any outcome is equivalent to one of three canonical outcomes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing is the concept of [natural density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)  As you take larger and larger finite sets starting at $1$, the fraction of red balls converges toward $\frac 13$  If it converges, you can reasonably say the probability of a red ball is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {\text {number of red balls in }[1,n]}n=\frac 13$

Comment: @Timothy:  I am quite aware that you can't have a uniform distribution on the naturals.  Natural density is a way of getting around that, which works nicely when things are periodic.  It justifies taking the probability over one period because when you have lots of periods a fractional period at the end gets less and less important.  Here we can can do the $\epsilon-N$ proof.  You tell me what $\epsilon$ you want and I can tell you an $N$ that if you take at least $N$ balls at the start you have a chance within $\epsilon$ of $\frac 13$ of getting a green ball.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you can define the probability of picking a number 1 more than a multiple of 3 as $\frac{1}{3}$. Maybe one way around it is to give an entirely different definition of probability and define the probability of picking a number that's 1 more than a multiple of 3 to be $\frac{1}{3}$. However, if you insist on making the additional assumption that the probability of each individual positive integer is between 0 and 1 and its sum over all positive integers is 1, and that the probability of picking any number 1 more than a multiple of 3 is the sum over all positive

Comment: integers 1 more than a multiple of 3 of their probabilities, you can derive a contradiction. I guess you can drop assumptions and consistently assert that the probability of picking a number 1 more than a multiple of 3 is $\frac{1}{3}$. Maybe I'm missing a feel for your explanation of how it's possible and it's too hard for me to learn to get a feel for it.

Comment: It is the way natural density is defined.  You compute the probability that the number is $1 \bmod 3$ when you draw uniformly out of $\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$, then take the limit as $n\to \infty$.  The error from $\frac 13$ is less than $\frac 1n$, so the probability converges to $\frac 13$.  So when $n=9$ the chance the number is $1 \bmod 3$ is exactly $\frac 13. $  When $n=10$ the chance is $\frac 4{10}$, rather greater.  But let $n=3000$ and the chance is again $\frac 13,$ when $n=3001$ the chance is $\frac {1001}{3001}$ which is quite close to $\frac 13$.  When this process converges...

Comment: which it doesn't always, we call that the natural density and it makes sense to call that the probability over the infinite sample.  That was the point of my original answer.

Comment: I think I get it. English is flexible. You're defining probability another way. I don't know if you got it from other people who already defined it that way before.

Comment: I gave a Wikipedia reference in the answer.  It is quite a standard approach.  It lets you say the density of primes is zero because they get rarer and rarer, for example.

Comment: They used the word "density," not "probability."

Answer (score 1):

Using the intuitive definition of probability leads to issues here, but the measure-theory based probability was formulated to deal with such things. There indeed you can define the probability measure in such a way that event of drawing a green ball has a measure of $1/3$...

Comment: You can also define a probability measure in such a way that the even to drawing a green ball has measure other than 1/3.

Comment: ... but there is no such thing as a uniform distribution on a countable set.

Comment: However, finitely additive "measures" can be used.

Comment: Well, we can indeed find measures that give green probability $\frac{1}{3}$. But "most" measures won't.

Comment: Perhaps the sample space should be $\Omega = \{ \{ 1,4,7,10,...\}, \{2,5,8,11,...\},\{3,6,9,12,...\} \}$ instead?