# Probability distribution for bounded choice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following setup and I am wondering how to model the probability distribution.

1. In a black box there are n*m balls each of which has one of n-colors.
2. I pick one at random and remove it from the box and record what color it was.
3. When the box is empty, I put all the n*m balls them back in and restart the experiment.

If I repeat this sampling and reset process to infinity, what should the expected value for each color be? I believe it will be a uniform distribution but not sure how to prove it.

EDIT: I think the solution I am looking for is undefined.
I am interested at the frequency with which I pick red balls, call this function `f_red: Nat -> Nat Mod m` it takes an argument `t \in Nat` which indicates which iteration of step 2 is currently executed.

For example

- At t = 0: `f_red(0) = 0 mod m` with probability 1, I haven't picked any balls yet.
- At t = 1: `f_red(1) = 1 mod m` with probability `1/m` (picked a red) or `0` with probability `m-1/m`.
- At t = n*m-1: `f_red(nm-1) = 0 mod m`  or `m-1 mod m`, in the second case we know we will pick a red with probability `1`.
- At t = n*m: `f_red(nm) =  0 mod m` with probability 1.
- Obviously the equation `f_red(t) mod m = f_red(t kod n*m) mod m` holds because we start over at multiples of `n*m`.

I was asking in particular about the behavior of `f_red` for `lim_t -> infinity`. But because it is not continuous, at the points `0 mod m`, the limit is undefined.

Forgetting about the limit, is it possible to estimate the expected value of `f_red`?

Comment: I am likely missing something - but if you extract all the balls every time, then the distribution should be the initial distribution before sampling.

Comment: Yes, the initial distribution is uniform over all n*m choices. However, after m choices of say, a red ball, then the probability of picking red falls to 0. But my question is about the expected frequency of each color if we repeat this experiment to infinity. So say you got all n*m balls out, then you for sure picked m red balls. The next time we reset the experiment you could pick only red balls, so the distribution would be at that point 2*m red, m all the other colors.

Comment: If each experiment is conducted until the box is empty, each time you have picked the entire lot !

Comment: Your problem, as written, is unclear. Since you are pulling out all of the balls, the random order you pick them in does not matter. The only randomness that matters is the randomness used to assign colors to the balls, but you have not specified the manner in which the colors are randomly assigned. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4752804/edit) to clarify. Better yet, if this is a metaphor for some applied problem, please tell use the context, as this helps to clarify.

Comment: Edited, let me know if it is still not clear what I am asking.

Comment: I think the concept of Natural density is what I want https://math.stackexchange.com/a/604705/1209458